# A class with ~40 constants should be declared static or non static?

Tags: c#

There is a class which just holds ~40 constants and this class can be declared as "static" as well as "Non static", as it doesn't have any impact on how we access these constants.

My question is which to prefer and Why? What's the best practice here to follow?

```
public static class IdConstants
{
    public const string a1= "a1" 
    // 40 more constants
}

public class IdConstants
{
    public const string a1= "a1" 
    // 40 more constants
}
```

Comment: If you're not going to instantiate the class - make it static.

Comment: as a `const` object is always `static`per definition, I would go with a `static class` if there are no other properties/methods which make sense on a instance level.

Comment: At this point, the more important question is probably whether these 40 constant strings are the *correct* way to model your situation. It's the sort of numbers where it wouldn't be at all surprising if a 41st or 42nd would come along and do you really want to be recompiling to support that? On the other hand, it may be that one or more enums is more appropriate than standalone constants.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am just trying to understand how enum could be better option instead of 40 standalone constants. These constants aren't related, however it has same type. Coming to concern of recompilation, I see something on MSDN, that makes me more confused:   `Just as with any constant, all references to the individual values of an enum are converted to numeric literals at compile time. This can create potential versioning issues as described in Constants.` [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum)

Comment: If these constants "aren't related", why are you putting all of them in a single class? Don't put everything in the same container just because they're of the same "type" (i.e. a constant)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever.. It is being used as "kind of utility" class and these are automation ids for UI controls. These constants will be referenced by multiple classes. And I kept it under a single class so that in case if ids changes,we just update single class instead of updating in multiple classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class should be `static` not because it declares constants but, because it **only** declares constants so, it will never be instantiated.

If the class has non-static members or will be inherited, then it should not be `static`.

---

As an aside, a class of the form

```
public static class IdConstants
{
    public const string a1 = "a1";
    public const string a2 = "a2"; 
    // ...
    public const string a41 = "a41";
}
```

would be indicative of a questionable design but I suspect you just wanted to illustrate your question with a quick example.